# SQL: How to Delete rows that match from table2 AND key from table3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

Table1: entitylink_test
parent_entity_id | child_entity_id
           1              |           11
           1                       |           12
                2                      |             13

Table2: vm_host_id
vm_id                 |    host_id
         11              |           1
          12                      |           1
               14                      |             15

Table3: tagstorage
 entity_id              |    tag_id
         11              |           80
          12                      |           85
               20                      |            80

I want to delete from entitylink_test the rows where entitylink_test.child_entity_id = vm_host_id.vm_id and where tagstorage = 80

So far, I have tried

```
DELETE FROM entitylink_test
WHERE entitylink_test.child_entity_id = vm_host_id.vm_id
AND tagstorage.tag_id = 80;
```

And I've tried

```
DELETE entitylink_test
FROM entitylink_test INNER JOIN vm_host_id
    ON entitylink_test.child_entity_id = vm_host_id.vm_id
    INNER JOIN tagstorage
      ON entitylink_test.child_entity_id = tagstorage.entity_id
      WHERE tagstorage = 80;
```

However, I keep getting the error "Unknown column 'vm_host_id.vm_id' in 'where clause'" for the first code, and "Unknown column 'tagstorage' in 'where clause'" for the second. Any other suggestions for syntax?

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
DELETE entitylink_test
FROM entitylink_test INNER JOIN vm_host_id
    ON entitylink_test.child_entity_id = vm_host_id.vm_id
    INNER JOIN tagstorage
      ON entitylink_test.child_entity_id = tagstorage.entity_id
      WHERE tagstorage.tag_id = 80;
```

You were referring to the table `tagstorage`, a table doesn't have a value, so you should specify which attribute of the table should have value `80`.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you so much! My eyes are so tired I couldn't spot that mistake haha

Comment: Sometimes it's easy :P